# Count where age is going to be 60 in next 3 years onward

Tags: sql, date

I have to count all the teachers whose ages are going to be 60 at June 2013, June 2014 and June 2015.
Details : at 2013 there is one teacher 2014 there is 5 teachers same etc.

I don't know how to get the three next years with June and count the number of teachers whose age will be 60 at June 2013, June 2014 and June 2015.

Here is the table:

```
TeacherName         DateOfBirth               TeacherAge    june2013    june2014    june2015
S. KHALID SALIM     1958-03-23 00:00:00.000   55            
ZUBAIDA BEGUM       1976-08-01 00:00:00.000   36            
TANZEEM AKHTAR      1974-09-25 00:00:00.000   38            
MARYAM BIBI         1982-08-18 00:00:00.000   30            
RABIA TABASSUM      1976-11-10 00:00:00.000   36
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  TeacherName, DateOfBirth,
  datediff(mm, DateOfBirth, getdate()) / 12 as TeacherAge,
  '' as  june2013(countteachers) , '' as june2014(countteachers), '' as june2015(countteachersonlywhoseagewillbe60atjune2015)
FROM Teachers
```

Comment: Here is my SQL query which need to be complet and correct
SELECT  TeacherName,DateOfBirth,datediff(mm, DateOfBirth, getdate()) / 12 as TeacherAge, '' as  june2013 ,'' as june2014,'' as june2015
from Teachers

Comment: you mean, all that have 60th birthday in one of those 3 junes? Please note that there is no standard with date functions, so without specifying the database engine your question is unasnwerable.

Comment: No : i have these three dates JUNE2013,JUNE2014, JUNE2015 now i want to count number of teachers whose age will be completed 60 in jun2013 or june2014 or june2015 i need to count all of teachers

Comment: What do you mean by 'completed in june 2013'?

Comment: if there is a teacher whose date of birth is 1958-03-23 first we need to calculate the age from this date of birth which is 55 years in the query now second , i need to count if some  teachers are going to be 60 in next june ie 2014 then just count if not then 0 same case is for all

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @dob  DATETIME, @june2013date DATETIME, @june2014date DATETIME
SET @dob='1980-01-09 00:00:00'
SET @june2013date='2013-06-01 00:00:00'
SET @june2014date='2014-06-01 00:00:00'


SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,GETDATE())/8766  AS Age, 
   DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,@june2013date)/8766 AS June2013Age, 
   DATEDIFF(hour,@dob,@june2014date)/8766 AS June2014Age
```

It should return something like this:

```
Age         June2013Age June2014Age
----------- ----------- -----------
33          33          34
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to count all teachers that will finish 60 years in June 2013/2014/2015?

It's really a constraint on birthday:

```
select count(*) from teachers where 
    dateofbirth between '1953-06-01' and '1953-06-30 23:59:58'
    OR dateofbirth between '1954-06-01' and '1954-06-30 23:59:58'
    OR dateofbirth between '1955-06-01' and '1955-06-30 23:59:58'
```

Comment: yes u ar rit we have to count it from date of birthday but against the three dates we have to compare it with the above three yers date if a teacher age lies in it ie if age is 60 then we will count